# Providing Required Format Information in Text Box in MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How do you set a string to denote the required format pattern in a text box. For instance, if I have a text box displayed such as a date field, how do I display a format of "dd/mm/yyyy" to help the User complete the field. If the field is already populated when the view is displayed then the actual data should be displayed.

If the field is a drop down list, I would like to display "Please select from the list" if the field does not contain a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML 5 you can achieve it using Placeholder attribute of input tag like this:

```
<input name="email" type="email" placeholder="validemail@email.com" />
```

However HTML5 is not yet supported by most browsers, so you will have to live with javascript based solution. Populate the desired value in textbox when page is loading (you can use CSS to make that text dim). Using javascript empty the field on "onfocus" event.

For drop down list populate "please select..." thing with Value as 0. This way you can validate on server that user has not selected any valid value.